# Is the space of bounded linear operators from E (space with an inner product) to C (complex numbers) a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

In other words is there an inner product that produces the operator norm?

Let $E$ be a space with an inner product. Show that its topological dual $E^*$ equiped with the operator norm is a Hilbert space. $E^*=\{f:E\to \Bbb C,\quad f\text{ is linear and bounded}\} $

Comment: I doubt that the linear bounded endomorphisms form a Hilbert space in general case. If it was the case, we would be spared much hassle with the spectral norm for matrices ($\Bbb R^n$ is a particular case of many functional spaces).

Comment: I've been given this as an excercise asking me to prove that it is a Hilbert a space. I'll write it as given in case I made a mistake.

Comment: You're asked for the dual. The space of linear operators is the space of maps $E\to E$, so your title is misleading.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll change it

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be Hilbert space. By Riesz representation theorem for any bounded linear functional $F\in H'$ there exists a unique element $g\in H$ such that $$\forall h\in H\quad f(h)=(g,h)_H.$$ We will denote this isomorphism by $i:H'\to H$

Apparently $\|f\|_{H'}= \|g\|_H$. Now take a scalar product in $H'$ by $$(f_1,f_2)_{H'} = (i(f_1),i(f_2))_{H}.$$

All you need to show is that the norm induced by this inner product is the same as the usual operator norm.

Comment: I have tried that but I do not know that the given space is complete and even if I tried to set for x belonging to H, f(y) = <y,x> , for any y in H then the function from H -> H* turns to be antilinear.

Comment: Unless antilinearity does not affect the isometry. Does it?

Comment: @Amontillado $H$ and $H'$ are both complete; the first one by definition, the second one - by a theorem. Antilinearity does not affect isometry.

Comment: In my given problem the original space is not Hilbert, it's just a space with an inner product, so I cannot assume the existence of the best approximation. But anyway thanks, if antilinearity doesn't affect isometry then I can go around the non-complete space! I'll rate it as answered since I got the answer in the comments!

Comment: Wait, I'm stuck again. If E is not complete then the f:E->E* is not surjective. So f(E) =/= E*. If somehow I show that f(E) is dense in E* then I'm finished. Any ideas?

Comment: @Amontillado that's an interesting question. I'll try to find something.